# Why does my app keeps stopping and shows error

Tags: android

I tried to create horizontal RecyclerView and bottom Navigation Bar
I made horizontal_card_item.xml, HorizontalView.kt (class), DataSource.kt , and HorizontalViewAdapter File, for recyclerView.

Here's my code of Main Activity.kt

```
class MainActivity(val myData: Array<String>) : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var horizontalViewAdapter: HorizontalViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        initRecyclerView()
        addDataSet()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(){

        val recycler_view = null
        recycler_view.apply {
            var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            val topSpacingDecorator = TopSpacingItemDecoration(30)
            addItemDecoration(topSpacingDecorator)
            horizontalViewAdapter = HorizontalViewAdapter()
            var adapter = horizontalViewAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun addDataSet(){
        val data = DataSource.createDataSet()
        //HorizontalViewAdapter.SubmitList(data)
    }

    private fun addItemDecoration(topSpacingDecorator: TopSpacingItemDecoration) {

    }


}
```

This is the logcat error that my app is showing

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.riddhi.rift, PID: 9780
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.riddhi.rift/com.riddhi.rift.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.riddhi.rift.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.riddhi.rift.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MainActivity(val myData: Array<String>) : AppCompatActivity() {
```

should be :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
```

An activity class cannot have parameters.

Comment: But now i recieved an error 2020-06-07 01:22:58.125 10346-10346/com.riddhi.rift E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-06-07 01:22:58.154 10346-10402/com.riddhi.rift E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

Comment: Kindly create a new SO post and comment on the link here. I will check it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238387/i-created-horizontal-cards-but-they-arent-showing-in-my-fragments