# I created horizontal cards but they arent showing in my fragments?

Tags: android

I tried to create horizontal `RecyclerView` and `Bottom Navigation View`.
I made `horizontal_card_item.xml`, `HorizontalView.kt` (class), `DataSource.kt` , and `HorizontalViewAdapter` File, for recyclerView.

***Main Activity.kt:***

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var horizontalViewAdapter: HorizontalViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        initRecyclerView()
        addDataSet()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        val recycler_view = null
        recycler_view.apply {
            var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            val topSpacingDecorator = TopSpacingItemDecoration(30)
            addItemDecoration(topSpacingDecorator)
            horizontalViewAdapter = HorizontalViewAdapter()
            var adapter = horizontalViewAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun addDataSet(){
        val data = DataSource.createDataSet()
        //  HorizontalViewAdapter.SubmitList(data)
    }

    private fun addItemDecoration(topSpacingDecorator: TopSpacingItemDecoration) {}
}
```

***Error:***

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
```

Comment: Why you set `recycler_view = null`? You should initialize it first `val recycler_view = findViewById(R.id.YOURS_RECYCLER_ID)`

Comment: Plus I dont think you need the "var" before the adapter, it already knows that adapter variable exists.

Comment: Because 'findViewById' is showing an error 'Not enough information to infer type variable T' @ZSergei

Comment: Using this [adapter = horizontalViewAdapter] shows an error in adapter of [Unresolved reference: adapter] @Goodie123

Comment: val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_id) and then do the apply without the val. It doesnt know what type of variable it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works. If not, post the issue you face after this change.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var horizontalViewAdapter: HorizontalViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        initRecyclerView()
        addDataSet()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        val recycler_view = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        recycler_view.apply {
            var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            val topSpacingDecorator = TopSpacingItemDecoration(30)
            addItemDecoration(topSpacingDecorator)
            horizontalViewAdapter = HorizontalViewAdapter()
            recycler_view.adapter = horizontalViewAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun addDataSet(){
        val data = DataSource.createDataSet()
        horizontalViewAdapter.updateData(data)
    }

    private fun addItemDecoration(topSpacingDecorator: TopSpacingItemDecoration) {}
}
```

***HorizontalViewAdapter:***

```
class HorizontalViewAdapter {

    fun updateData(data) {
        this.data = data

        // Notify that the data is changed
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    // Everything else
}
```

Comment: unresolved reference for [adapter] and [createDataSet()]

Comment: @RiddhiDua Please add the new error in the question. Possibly with the error line.
We can continue our conversation here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215419/abhis-chat-room